# attr ColorForeground vs WindowBackground

Tags: android, android-attributes

I'm going to make my own theme not inheriting android's theme.

So, I refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html but I can't understand mostly from it.

I know `android:windowBackground` is background, but what is `android:colorForeground`, `android:colorBackground`, `android:colorBackgroundCacheHint` for?

And do I have to state all attributes?(by android theme's attr) Because, for example, `android:backgroundDimAmount` is not used for anything in `styles_holo.xml` or `styles.xml`. (by android style's) Is it used in Constructor?